# How to animate a div at the same time as slideToggle hide/show

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a new website, where I have a contact 'tab' coming from the top of the browser window. Here's the link: http://www.stefanhagen.nl/testlab/. If you click the tab, a contact form will appear (using slideToggle). But while the contact form appears, I want the tab to slide down with the contact form, as if the user 'pulls' the form inside the browser window. I now use slideToggle to show the contact form on clicking the tab. Where do I put the code to animate the tab itself? By the way: I have a liquid layout, so the tab isn't 'pushed down' like normal, because I use absolute positioning for every div. Thanx in advance, and here's my JQuery so far:

```
$('div.contacttab').click(function(){

$('div.contactform').slideToggle('slow', function(){

});
```

Comment: What kind of magic you used?? When I ctrl+mouseScrolled (too zoom in) the text didn't get bigger

Comment: I'm using javascript to change the text size according to window size, so if you alter the size of you're window, all the proportions remain the same. So the text gets smaller/bigger. But you should be able to zoom in, so I will look in to that this weekend;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest placing the contact tab into the same container div as the form then positioning it off page (with only the contact tab showing) then sliding it into view when clicked so that they move together like this:

```
<div class="contactformulier" style="top: -350px;">
    <div id="inputarea" style="height: 350px;">
        <form action="php/contactengine.php" method="post">
        ....
        </form>
    </div><!--closes the #contact-area div -->
    <div class="contacttab" style="position: relative"><p>Contact</p></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.contacttab').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            // Show Contact Form //
            if (parseFloat$('.contactformulier').css('top') < 0)
                $('.contactformulier').animate({'top' : '0px' }, 'fast');
            }
            // Hide Contact Form //
            else {
                $('.contactformulier').animate({'top' : '-350px' }, 'fast');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanx for your solutions! Just one problem: My contact form has fixed proportions, but the TAB is 'liquid'. That means that I gave it a width and height using % instead of px. I'd like to maintain this, so if the window is scaled down, or someone views the site on a small screen, the tab does not stay the same (to big) size. But if I put the tab and the form together in a container div, the tab will not scale to the window size, but to the size of the container div (wich will stay the same, because of the fixed with of the form). I hope it's clear (english is not my native language). Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

I'd put the contact tab and the contact form div inside of a wrapper, and slide the wrapper down when the tab is clicked. That way, the tab moves with the form div.